# Order of SQL Server backup restore

Tags: sql-server, restore

An general doubt about how restore in done in SQL server

While performing restore, will the MDF and NDF will be restored first or the LDF files?

Comment: Why does it matter? The restore is going to succeed or fail as a whole.

Comment: Seriously it doesn't matter, but an developer asked me this and I really don't know genuine answer to him. So this keeps bugging me. ha

Comment: I think, by just logic, the data files need to be restored first, so the logs may be implemented after.

Comment: Why would the developer even ask this?

Comment: Probably they are testing me :P . Developer team were analysing an restore job from vendor , so had some clarifications on storage and which files will be saved first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the very wise folks in the comments, who noted that this doesn't matter.

And, in terms of what's actually going on in the files, I don't know. None of the files is usable until the restore process is done. So, again, doesn't matter.

Now, what *might* matter, is when the files are created, and when they reach full size. Especially if the devs were looking at storage during the process.

Just did a quick test to confirm that what I thought I knew, I actually knew. And, as I thought, my MDF and LDF files were both created when the restore started, and are created at full size (whatever size they were before they were backed up). [Technically, the files are created at size 0, then inflated (still empty) to the proper size, then filled; however, the time between creation and inflation will usually be infinitesimally smaller than the time between the inflation and the completion of the filling]

I don't have backups with an NDF file to confirm with, unfortunately. However, I would expect that to behave similarly (with the possible exception of restoring a pre-2008 backup to a 2008+ server, which allows for the full-text indexes to be rebuilt or reset, if appropriate).

Comment: Just to be clear, those are considered "containers" and must exist before the data can be "streamed" into them. You have the right idea :) I would ask you to take it a *step* further, run the restore **BUT** hook up process monitor before you do that and filter on the folder you restore to. Then you should update the answer with your results :)